How to set max-height based on width (Maximum aspect ratio)
I try to define a maximum aspect ratio for an element (css only).
For example I want to set maximum aspect ratio to 1/1.
If the element have a width of 500px and a height of 200px then do not change the anything.
If the element have a width of 500px and a height of 600px then limit the height to 500px


.container { width: 50%;  }
.element{ background: #ccc; margin-top: 10px; }
<div class="container">
  <div class="element">This element should not change</div>
  <div class="element">This div height should be cut because aspect ratio is bigger than 1/1

<small>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in lectus eu nulla consequat malesuada at vitae eros. Nulla facilisi. Donec purus nulla, egestas vitae molestie vel, pellentesque condimentum turpis. Quisque ullamcorper tincidunt velit vel pharetra. Maecenas et massa bibendum, tincidunt mauris at, pulvinar mi. Curabitur ut porta sem, in dapibus justo. Phasellus vitae consequat erat. Aenean non facilisis eros.

  Aenean placerat urna sit amet libero viverra congue. Maecenas interdum nunc quam. Nam placerat massa fermentum urna aliquam, eu consequat nunc sollicitudin. Etiam elementum sapien ac orci bibendum efficitur. Cras congue enim sit amet sollicitudin ultrices. Duis convallis mi felis. Nulla a ipsum tempor, eleifend tellus scelerisque, bibendum neque. Nulla erat elit, bibendum vitae commodo eu, finibus eget nibh. Phasellus non dictum lectus. Quisque at eros nibh. Cras fermentum, ex eu eleifend placerat, arcu justo sodales tellus, et cursus mi mauris ac ante. Aliquam vel arcu mi. Duis condimentum nisi orci, id interdum lectus suscipit eu.

  Phasellus eu laoreet sem. Cras nec placerat sapien. Aliquam eget efficitur libero. Etiam velit velit, interdum in turpis eget, tincidunt sagittis neque. Pellentesque a feugiat risus. Donec sagittis odio libero, eu tristique ipsum hendrerit quis. Vestibulum porttitor eros erat, vitae accumsan magna ultricies vel. Vestibulum laoreet augue eu quam dictum maximus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce accumsan mollis cursus. Sed et ligula tellus. Donec faucibus justo id fermentum sodales.

  Donec non sapien et turpis dignissim hendrerit. Nam eget ultrices est. Integer lacinia bibendum tortor, eget vestibulum eros lacinia sit amet. Vivamus non nisl feugiat, mattis mi ut, ultricies leo. In blandit fermentum nisi, ut sagittis neque congue id. Duis quis elementum metus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec lectus nisi, ultricies euismod metus in, tempor vulputate velit. Proin pellentesque auctor magna eleifend fermentum. Proin rhoncus augue eu hendrerit accumsan.

  Aliquam ac elit suscipit, dignissim sem quis, lobortis tellus. Nunc justo nulla, vulputate et blandit a, luctus eu lorem. Etiam et turpis sit amet ante tempus dictum eget iaculis sem. Mauris augue est, laoreet sit amet euismod a, posuere in lorem. Morbi ut dapibus odio. Morbi tincidunt, magna ac cursus dapibus, arcu dui volutpat libero, sit amet fermentum tellus arcu quis tellus. Proin vitae tortor risus. Nunc sed congue sapien. Fusce luctus, metus euismod bibendum rutrum, metus ipsum semper sem, at dictum ante diam a mauris. Sed commodo posuere enim. Etiam scelerisque bibendum orci in ornare. Phasellus sit amet nulla nulla. Fusce ut erat mi.</small>
  </div>
</div>




You can do that with max-height css properties to ensures the height of the .element does not exceed the 1:1 ratio, and add a overflow: hidden; to ensure that any element exceeding the ratio is not visible
I tried this, it should solve your problem :


document.querySelectorAll(".element").forEach((el) => {
  const width = el.offsetWidth;
  const height = el.offsetHeight;

  if (height > width) {
    // If the height exceeds the width, enforce a 1:1 ratio
    el.style.height = `${width}px`;
  }
});
.container {
  width: 50%;
}

.element {
  background: #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;

  width: 100%;
  height: auto; 
  overflow: hidden;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>HTML + CSS</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="element">This element should not change</div>
      <div class="element">
        This div height should be cut because aspect ratio is bigger than 1/1

        <small>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in lectus
          eu nulla consequat malesuada at vitae eros. Nulla facilisi. Donec
          purus nulla, egestas vitae molestie vel, pellentesque condimentum
          turpis. Quisque ullamcorper tincidunt velit vel pharetra. Maecenas et
          massa bibendum, tincidunt mauris at, pulvinar mi. Curabitur ut porta
          sem, in dapibus justo. Phasellus vitae consequat erat. Aenean non
          facilisis eros. Aenean placerat urna sit amet libero viverra congue.
          Maecenas interdum nunc quam. Nam placerat massa fermentum urna
          aliquam, eu consequat nunc sollicitudin. Etiam elementum sapien ac
          orci bibendum efficitur. Cras congue enim sit amet sollicitudin
          ultrices. Duis convallis mi felis. Nulla a ipsum tempor, eleifend
          tellus scelerisque, bibendum neque. Nulla erat elit, bibendum vitae
          commodo eu, finibus eget nibh. Phasellus non dictum lectus. Quisque at
          eros nibh. Cras fermentum, ex eu eleifend placerat, arcu justo sodales
          tellus, et cursus mi mauris ac ante. Aliquam vel arcu mi. Duis
          condimentum nisi orci, id interdum lectus suscipit eu. Phasellus eu
          laoreet sem. Cras nec placerat sapien. Aliquam eget efficitur libero.
          Etiam velit velit, interdum in turpis eget, tincidunt sagittis neque.
          Pellentesque a feugiat risus. Donec sagittis odio libero, eu tristique
          ipsum hendrerit quis. Vestibulum porttitor eros erat, vitae accumsan
          magna ultricies vel. Vestibulum laoreet augue eu quam dictum maximus.
          Aliquam erat volutpat. Fusce accumsan mollis cursus. Sed et ligula
          tellus. Donec faucibus justo id fermentum sodales. Donec non sapien et
          turpis dignissim hendrerit. Nam eget ultrices est. Integer lacinia
          bibendum tortor, eget vestibulum eros lacinia sit amet. Vivamus non
          nisl feugiat, mattis mi ut, ultricies leo. In blandit fermentum nisi,
          ut sagittis neque congue id. Duis quis elementum metus. Interdum et
          malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Donec lectus nisi,
          ultricies euismod metus in, tempor vulputate velit. Proin pellentesque
          auctor magna eleifend fermentum. Proin rhoncus augue eu hendrerit
          accumsan. Aliquam ac elit suscipit, dignissim sem quis, lobortis
          tellus. Nunc justo nulla, vulputate et blandit a, luctus eu lorem.
          Etiam et turpis sit amet ante tempus dictum eget iaculis sem. Mauris
          augue est, laoreet sit amet euismod a, posuere in lorem. Morbi ut
          dapibus odio. Morbi tincidunt, magna ac cursus dapibus, arcu dui
          volutpat libero, sit amet fermentum tellus arcu quis tellus. Proin
          vitae tortor risus. Nunc sed congue sapien. Fusce luctus, metus
          euismod bibendum rutrum, metus ipsum semper sem, at dictum ante diam a
          mauris. Sed commodo posuere enim. Etiam scelerisque bibendum orci in
          ornare. Phasellus sit amet nulla nulla. Fusce ut erat mi.</small
        >
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>



Hope this helps

This doesn't work. Juste check the height of second element. The goal is to make the ratio 1:1 as maximum.

Oh sorry i missunderstood something
"If the element have a width of 500px and a height of 600px then limit the width to 500px" So you meant the height rather than the width here?

Yes exact my bad

Is it ok to include javascript to check a condition? Because I have to admit that with css alone, I don't really see how you can achieve that, assuming that the first element doesn't have to change at all.

I've updated the answer with javascript, let me know if it's good for you now

Thank's for trying but my goal is to achieve that with css only.
